# Syncfusion ejGrid not displaying (uncaught reference and uncaught type error)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, syncfusion

I have recently been introduced to syncfusion and I am trying to use their basic grid feature.

I have html code as show in the fiddle and a separate js file called orders which contains:

```
        $("#Grid").ejGrid({           

        columns: [

            { field: "Order", headerText: "Order ID", width: 75, textAlign: ej.TextAlign.Right },

            { field: "CustomerID", headerText: "Customer ID", width: 80 },

            { field: "ShipName", headerText: "Ship Name", width: 100 },

            { field: "ShipCity", headerText: "Ship City", width: 100 },

            { field: "Freight", width: 80, format: "{0:C3}", textAlign: ej.TextAlign.Right }

        ]

    });
```

Basically, I'm trying to get a table to display in Section 3 but keep on getting this error:

> jquery.easing.min.js:44 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
>   jquery.easing.min.js:44(anonymous function)
>
> ej.web.all-latest.min.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'extend' of undefined ej.web.all-latest.min.js:10(anonymous function)
>   ej.web.all-latest.min.js:10(anonymous function)
>
> orders.js:30 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
>   orders.js:30(anonymous function)

I've tried using the js directly as a script tag within html but that doesn't work. I've also tried wrapping it in a document.ready function but to no avail.

JsFiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/Ld6mn6xb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the fiddle, you have referred the `jquery easing` before `jquery` and hence the issue occurred and also remove multiple jquery files.

Please find the working fiddle here

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ld6mn6xb/1/)

And also refer the below help link for getting started with `Syncfusion ejGrid`.

[ejGrid help](http://help.syncfusion.com/ug/js/default.htm#!documents/createyourfirstgridi.htm)

For now in the above fiddle, i have provided empty data to the grid since `order.js` file is not found in the fiddle.